# Crowdfunding payment gateway for Europe (Portugal specifically)

Tags: paypal

i am implementing paypal adaptive payments for my little crowdfunding site and I see that actually Paypal doesnt give a choice for non-US devs.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq#non-US-dev

Has anyone found out any other solution to this problem, for crowdfunding in European countries, specifically Spain or Portugal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you managed to get any solution? I'm with the same problem, more appropriately for payments in mobile applications in Porttugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive Payments is available in any of the countries that PayPal supports.  The page that you linked to is specifically referring to the REST API, which is a different product and is only available in the US at this time.

You can sign up for Adaptive Payments by going to https://apps.paypal.com.